# How many kill signals this program needs to be terminqted

Tags: c, linux, signals

I was given the program below in an exam and the question was how many kill signals must be sent to the process in order to terminate it. My answer was 3 signals, but the professor insisted on only 2 signals are needed to terminate the process? How is so?

```
static void action(int sig)
{
    signal(SIGINT,SIG_DFL);
}
int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT,SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGUSR1,action);
    while(1)
        pause();
}
```

Comment: You (should) only ever need one `kill -9`... (Zombie-infection notwithstanding)

Comment: We're not talking in general here, we're talking about how many kills must be sent to this program as it desires.

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention the only signals to be used are SIGUSR1 and SIGINT

Comment: @Kninnug In this particular case, any of TERM, ILL, SEGV, ABRT, HUP, BUS, QUIT, FPE, XCPU or XFSZ would probably work just fine, too...

Comment: Race condition. You only need *one* `SIGINT` to terminate the process, provided the signal is received *before* the first call to `signal()` is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send SIGUSR1 to invoke the `action`. And all `action` does is set SIGINT to its default signal handler (SIG_DFL). Then you send the SIGINT, that then triggers the default handler which terminates the process.

**NOTE:** It must be done in that order, any attempt to send SIGINT before SIGUSR1 will be ignored because of the bind to SIG_IGN.

Comment: Thank you for the response.